# Unable to find how to start a service defined in docker image

Tags: docker-compose

I have created a docker image using `docker-compose build` and tagged it. Now, I have ported the image to a different machine and trying to bring the services up defined in docker-compose. But unfortunately, I am not able to figure out how to use `docker-compose up` with just the image tag without porting over the yml configuration file. I thought that it should be direct as the build image should contain the configuration.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to use `docker build` / `docker run`. Why are you using compose?